# Passing a general argument to function using template

Tags: c++, templates

There are some classes and their relationships are as follows:

```
class X:A,B
class Y:A,B
class Z:A,B
```

I want to pass a general type that will inherit from A and B to testFunction using template. My code is as follows:

```
template<template T:public A, public B>
void testFunction(T generalType)
{
    //do something
}
```

but my compiler told me that it's error template. How could I fix it?

Comment: Reopened this - the supposed duplicate was about a _class_. But unlike classes, functions have overloading. That means you want to _exclude_ specific functions from the overload set, rather then have them be selected in overload resolution and then break later on.

Comment: Why not simply write `template<template T>` and see if that works. I don't know how your application works, but it might be fine. Do you have other functions called `testFunction`?

Comment: @ MSalters @ Aaron McDaid @songyuanyao.  Thanks for all of your patient and careful answers.  With all your help,  my code pass the stage of compilation. I have learned a lot from all of you,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`template<template T:public A, public B>` is not valid syntax. You could check the type with [`std::is_base_of`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_base_of) and `static_assert`, which will trigger a compiler error if wrong type passed.

```
template <typename T>
void testFunction(T generalType)
{
    static_assert(std::is_base_of<A, T>::value && std::is_base_of<B, T>::value, "T must inherit from A and B.");
}
```

[DEMO](http://rextester.com/FSVT62229)

Answer (score 9):

The standard method to conditionally define a template is `std::enable_if<condition>`. In this case, you want to check the condition `std::is_base_of<A,T>::value && std::is_base_of<B,T>::value`